# Something for the real fans

Tags: riddle, cipher, geography, knowledge, movies

Terry guessed the key based on clues she got from Jack
In a music-linked movie roughly three decades back
But you need to start from a more continental track

From Harold G to Harrowing (as Schmieder once denoted)
Led to smoking at the theatre - no longer here promoted
Decrypt the next installment if you want to get upvoted

> XFMcvihqtfcLiuvnbzqqtfcvlshcgzafwxtzyqsrlwrgrbsmhzfxiihugqhjhhew Ojljlnhkhdfdbtwuowrvvorrpvvfhrggomcnhydflrbbvfocvvemrxelhyabhvu Riwrrvumrzruxiwykretjbqdannhyrggqbfwafkfzfwsjbusxabhvu

The answer should be 13 characters long.
And Len has already done a lot of the hard work!

**Hint**

> I could have used the word Harrying in place of Harrowing

Comment: Very nice puzzle with so many layers :-)

Comment: Is Terry the correct spelling?

Comment: @LeppyR64 It certainly is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Final Answer

> Is [Exhibitionism](http://www.stonesexhibitionism.com/).  I'm sure "real fans" will love this!

### The Riddle

**Stanza 1**

> This refers to [Jumpin' Jack Flash (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091306/). The song [Jumpin' Jack Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumpin%27_Jack_Flash) is in the key of B-Flat.  This is not the song that we're looking for however, we need a more "continental" track. 
> "Rule Britannia" and "God Save the Queen" are both "continental" and in the soundtrack for Jumpin' Jack Flash but neither is in the key of D Major (thanks Len)

**Stanza 2**

> Harold G refers to [Harold Godwinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Godwinson) who was killed at the Battle of Hastings in 1066.  The harrowing or [Harrying of the North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrying_of_the_North) occurred in 1069.
> Schmieder refers to [Wolfgang Schmieder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Schmieder) who indexes JS Bach's music.  BWV 1066-1069 are his Orchestral Suites.  1068 is the famous "Air on the G String" which was used as the jingle for Hamlet Cigars.  With the tobacco publishing ban in the UK they are no longer aired.  The key of this song is D Major.

### The Cipher

Using the key of

> DMAJOR

found above, the code is decrypted using a vigenere cipher, yielding:

> ```
> utm three two u five nine two eight six two five six four seven four eight seven
> ```
>
> ```
> a six letter function describes this place that links to the baroque master
> ```
>
> ```
> find a similar link to stanza one though not of bricks and plaster
> ```

**Line 1**

> UTM coordinate in zone 32 at eastings 592862 and northings 5647487 which converts to a WGS84 coordinate of 50.971488°N 10.322607°E - As seen in Len's answer.
> This is the location of Bacchaus, the home of Johann Sebastian Bach, the baroque master.

**Line 2**

> The six letter function of the Bachhaus is a museum.

**Line 3**

> The [Rolling Stones](http://www.rollingstones.com/) are beginning a museum exhibition in April 2016 called [Exhibitionism](http://www.stonesexhibitionism.com/)

Comment: Looking good so far.

Comment: Good work. The track you're after isn't from the film. Stanza one tells you how to find the key. Stanza two tells you where to find it. The Battle of Hastings was is the south.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer.  This cipher is a:

> Vigenere cipher that decodes to (with spaces added):
>
> **UTM three two U five nine two eight six two five six four seven four eight seven**
> **A six letter function describes this place that links to the baroque master**
> **Find a similar link to stanza one though not of bricks and plaster**
>
> The Vigenere key is **DMAJOR**

The first line of plaintext is a:

> UTM coordinate in zone 32 at eastings 592862 and northings 5647487
> which converts to a WGS84 coordinate of 50.971488°N 10.322607°E
> This location is very close to [**Bach House**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bach_House_(Eisenach)) in Eisenach, Germany

The second line of plaintext refers to:

> Johann Sebastian Bach as the baroque master who was born in Eisenach

Comment: Good progress, though you started in the middle. There must be an error with my Vigenere as I hadn't intended the one letter shift.

Comment: Though you've already decoded it, I've replaced the cipher for a version without the character shift.

Comment: @GordonK - Ok, I have modified to be consistent.